How to do two joins with mismatched data in PostgreSQL for schedules and actuals
In my app, we have users, projects, user_valid_days, schedules, and actuals. I'm wanting to produce a select statement that will produce an output that shows on which days a user has been scheduled and for how much time, as well has if the user has submitted any work against these projects on these days. All valid days should be shown regardless of whether or not the user was scheduled or worked on these days. If the day is invalid, then any scheduled/actualized hours should be dropped.
Given the following (as a db fiddle):
Database structure:
CREATE TABLE schedules (
    user_id int4 NULL,
    "date" date NULL,
    project_id int4 NULL,
    "time" int NULL
);

CREATE TABLE actuals (
    user_id int4 NULL,
    "date" date NULL,
    project_id int4 NULL,
    "time" int NULL
);

CREATE TABLE public.user_valid_dates (
    user_id int4 NULL,
    "date" date NULL
);

Example data:
INSERT INTO schedules (user_id, "date", project_id, time) VALUES (1, '2024-04-01', 101, 2), (1, '2024-04-01', 102, 2);
INSERT INTO actuals (user_id, "date", project_id, "time") VALUES (1, '2024-04-01', 101, 3), (1, '2024-04-01', 105, 4);
INSERT INTO user_valid_dates (user_id, "date") VALUES(1, '2024-04-01'), (1, '2024-04-02'), (1, '2024-04-03'), (1, '2024-04-04');

I'd love to produce data similar to:
+---------+------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+
| user_id | date       | project_id | scheduled_hours | worked_hours |
+---------+------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 1       | 2024-01-01 |            |                 |              |
+---------+------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 1       | 2024-01-02 | 1          | 1               | 0            |
+---------+------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 1       | 2024-01-02 | 2          | 0               | 1            |
+---------+------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 1       | 2024-01-03 | 1          | 1               | 1            |
+---------+------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 1       | 2024-01-04 |            |                 |              |
+---------+------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+

So that for a given day, I can know how many hours a user was scheduled and if they've submitted any time.
I've tried various select statements, such as:
select
    * 
from user_valid_dates uvd 
left join schedules s on s."date" = uvd."date" and s.user_id = uvd.user_id 
left join actuals a on a."date" = uvd."date" and a.user_id = uvd.user_id and ( a.project_id is null or a.project_id = s.project_id )

but can't get a select to produce a row where there is a no match between s.project_id = a.project_id
how can I fix this select? Or is there a different way to approach this altogether?

Please update your question so that the expected results data corresponds to the actual sample data provided. I.E. data contains no values for project_id existing in the results and assuming the column worked_hours comes from table actules then the values expected does not match your data. If work_hours does not come form actuals then what is the source.
